# cannot override a concrete member without a third member that's overridden by both

Tags: scala, scala-2.8

What does the following error message mean?

> cannot override a concrete member
>   without a third member that's
>   overridden by both (this rule is
>   designed to prevent ``accidental
>   overrides'');

I was trying to do stackable trait modifications. It's a little bit after the fact since I already have a hierarchy in place and I'm trying to modify the behavior without having to rewrite a lot of code.

I have a base class called AbstractProcessor that defines an abstract method sort of like this:

```
abstract class AbstractProcessor {
  def onPush(i:Info): Unit
}
```

I have a couple existing traits, to implement different onPush behaviors.

```
trait Pass1 {
  def onPush(i:Info): Unit = { /* stuff */ }
}

trait Pass2 {
  def onPush(i:Info): Unit = { /* stuff */ }
}
```

So that allows me to use `new AbstractProcessor with Pass1` or `new AbstractProcessor with Pass2`.

Now I would like to do some processing before and after the onPush call in Pass1 and Pass2 while minimizing code changes to AbstractProcessor and Pass1 and Pass2. I thought of creating a trait that does something like this:

```
trait Custom extends AbstractProcessor {
  abstract override def onPush(i:Info): Unit = {
    // do stuff before
    super.onPush(i)
    // do stuff after
  }
}
```

And using it with `new AbstractProcessor with Pass1 with Custom` and I got that error message.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that there is ambiguity between `AbstractProcessor.onPush` and `Pass1.onPush`. The latter is not overridding the former because `Pass1` does not extend `AbstractProcessor`.

If you make `Pass1` and `Pass2` extend `AbstractProcessor`, then the problem is solved.

Comment: By the time I got your answer I figured out I could create a trait for onPush and have everything extends that. I guess I got confused by the "third" word. I wonder if "without a base member that's overriden by both" would give a better clue.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to have a trait that contains just:

```
def onPush(i:Info): Unit
```

And mix that trait into `AbstractProcessor`, `Pass1`, and `Pass2`. The compiler will no longer try to prevent an "accidental override."